# Rspec-rails to many output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

rails 4.2.4 rspec 3.3.3

.rspec :

```
--color
```

in foo_spec.rb :

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

output:

```
 # /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:46:in `generate'
 # /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:729:in `generate'
 # /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:760:in `generate'
 # /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:755:in `generate_extras'
 # /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:750:in `extra_keys'
 # /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:208:in `assign_parameters'
 # /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@qna/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controlle...
```

How to disable this lines (#.../.rvm/...)?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What command are you running?

Comment: When I run rspec or rake, and test is red, I get standard error with lot of this lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually disable them, but you can `grep` them out in the output, something like this:

```
  <your rspec command> | grep -v '/.rvm/' # this command will filter out all lines, containing "/.rvm/" string
```